# Simulate latex \underbracket in html (ie write text below a specific part of a sentence)

Tags: css

I'm searching to obtain this effect

[image]

that is to place a bracket under a piece of text and then to write text below the said bracket. Is it possible to obtain such an effect using HTML and CSS? If not, also javascript can be used.

A "primitive" bracket can be obtained simply by adding a bottom-border to the selected text, such as

```
span.note { bottom-border: 1px solid }

The quick <span class=note>brown fox jumps over the</span> lazy dog.
```

But how to add text below the border?

---

I don't know if this effect has a name, I'm just trying to replicate the `\underbrace` or `\underbracket` latex commands, which are used in this way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\underbrace{a+b+c}_{d} \quad \underbracket{a+b+c}_{d}$
\end{document}
```

and generate this output

[image]

---

### NEW SOLUTION

With this code it is possible to put HTML code below the selected text, an example here

```css
.above {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  }
  .above::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1.5px currentcolor solid;
    border-top: 0;
    content: "";
  }
  .above .below {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 140%;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<p>The product <span class="above">2 · 2 · 2 <span class="below">2<sup>3</sup></span></span> can be written as power.</p>
```

Moreover, with this [How to horizontally center an annotation above a word in a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105151/how-to-horizontally-center-an-annotation-above-a-word-in-a-sentence) the text below can be centered in any condition.

Comment: The square brackets could work as a `div` with left-right-bottom borders. I don't know about the curved brackets.

Comment: If all else fails, SVG will do the trick.

Comment: @pensum yes, but then how to put text below the border?

Comment: @ThanhTrung is it possible to anchor a bubble to a piece of text?

Comment: @Brad what do you mean with SVG?

Comment: @soundwave SVG is a way to use vector graphics on the web.  You can create a path that looks like your bracket.  SVG supports text as well.  SVG uses XML markup, similar to that of HTML.  The downside is that positioning can be difficult, but you can make it work, even if you were to intermingle SVG with your HTML and position via JavaScript.

Comment: Another method to highlight like this, is to set the border-radius of the bottom corners of the tag (5px should do it). Setting the colour of the bottom border will give you a nicely curved bracket that tappers out after a few pixels at either end.

Comment: Also, you could set a `title` for the tag which will give you a tool-tip effect for your 'what if we remove this?' text.  Though not constantly displayed (i.e. the user must hover over the highlighted text), I personally think it would look tidier in the text flow; dropping text between the lines would make the whole thing look cluttered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `data-*` attribute for the text of the annotation along with the `content` property of a pseudoelement, e.g.

```css
p { font: 1rem/1.4 Arial; }

[data-annotation] {
  position    : relative;
  white-space : nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-annotation]::before,
[data-annotation]::after {
  position : absolute;
  z-index  : 1;  
  width  : 100%;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .5s 0s, color .5s 0s;
}

[data-annotation]::before {
  top    : calc(100% + 2px);
  height : 5px;
  border : 1px currentcolor solid;
  border-top : 0;
  content: "";
}

[data-annotation]::after {
  content    : attr(data-annotation);
  left       : 0;
  font-size  : .75em;
  text-align : center;
  top        : calc(100% + 10px);
  overflow   : hidden;
  text-overflow : ellipsis;
}

[data-annotation]:hover::before,
[data-annotation]:hover::after {
   opacity : 1;
   color   : #578;
}

[data-annotation]:hover::after {
   overflow : visible;
}
```

```html
<p>
   The quick brown <span data-annotation="What if we remove this?">fox jumps
   over the lazy</span> dog. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consectetur dolor 
   adisciplit elit, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy. Lorem ipsum 
   <span data-annotation="OMG this annotation is really long">sit dolor amet
   consectetur dolor adisciplit elit, the quick brown fox</span> jumps over 
   the lazy. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consectetur dolor adisciplit elit, 
   the <span data-annotation="Ooops short element, longer 
   annotation">quick brown</span> fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</p>
```

To avoid a line wrap inside the span I've used `white-space: nowrap` and I've inserted a `margin-bottom` so the following line is properly spaced from  the previous line.

The color of the border is set to `currentcolor` in order to match the color of the text. Also tried to insert a small opacity in order improve a bit the  legibility of the main text.

Comment: Wow this is pretty awesome! It has automatic size of the bracket, no javascript, easy implementation, all in a single span. I'm going to test this a bit thanks!

Comment: @fcalderan I'm testing your code in many cases, and until now it worked like a charm many thanks! I'm reading about the `z-index` property, and found out it specifies the stack order of an element. I tried removing it and the code worked as before, but do you suggest me to leave it in the code anyway? Thank you!

Comment: @soundwave usually I want to be aware of the stack order and I prefer to always declare it.

Comment: @fcalderan ok thanks! I tried putting some html inside `data-annotation`, for example `<span data-annotation="2<sup>3</sup>">something</span>`, but then in the annotation is shown `2<sup>3</sup>` instead of 2 with a small 3 at the top. Is there a way to process the html code given to `data-annotation`? Thank you again

Comment: Unfortunately no, the `content` property of a pseudoelement can't render html. Anyway for basic superscript use the  UTF-8 symbol (take a look at a unicode table)

Comment: I updated the question adding a new method which let us put html code below the text, what you think about it? Do you think it can be improved? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example with the *squared* brackets. As you can see, I used two paragraph tags and a div displaying only it's bottom-right-left borders.

```css
div#container {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

div#border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 143px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-left: 248px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
  <div id="border"></div>
  <p>what if we remove this?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice thanks! Do you think it is possible to set the border width automatically accordingly to the width of the text of interest?

Comment: I don't think so because your `div` width is independent of the paragraph on top. How then could he know the text of interest? ^^

Comment: Well you coud do it with javascript/jquery though you did say only html css

Comment: The developer has to choose himself the width of this stuff. There is no rule..

Comment: @123abc321bca is it hard with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative approach, and based on my comments, you could try a more simple tac...

```html
<p>
    The quick brown 
    <span class="syntax-hilite" title="What if we remove this?">
        fox jumped over the lazy
    </span>
    dog.
</p>
```

...and the CSS...

```css
span.syntax-hilite {
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this, and then move the div anywhere you want.

```css
img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  height: 23px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: -20px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.first {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <p class="first">Some amount of text</p><img src="https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/955/204/897/bracket-accolade-clip-art-curly-thumbnail.jpg"/>
  <p>something</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but in this way the bracket will not scale with font size, and a different size bracket image has to be generated for each length of the selected piece of text.