# How to horizontally center an annotation above a word in a sentence?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a css object which let me place an annotation above a specific word of a sentence, or above a part of the sentence. The annotation must always be visibile and has not to move the surrounding text.

It is quite easy to obtain the effect in the case the word is longer than the annotation, while I'm struggling to get it works in the opposite case, that is when the annotation is longer than the word below.

The `span` element seemed to me the best to do the job, but maybe it is not. I tried also with `table` element but I was not able to get neither of the two cases to work.

```css
p { font-size: 1.5em }

.highlight {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: red;
}

.highlight .annotation {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 80%;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>short <span class=highlight>fo<span class=annotation>foo baar foo</span></span> but not centered.</p>
<p>long <span class=highlight>fooooooooooo<span class=annotation>foo baar foo</span></span> and centered.</p>
```

To be more clear, this is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can center the annotation using `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`. The left attribute is in relation to the parent (50% of `.highlight`'s width), while `translateX` is in relation to the element (-50% of `.annotation`'s width).

```css
p {
  font-size: 1.5em
}

.highlight {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: red;
}

.highlight .annotation {
  position: absolute;
  /** remove width: 100%; **/ 
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 80%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 0.75em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>short <span class=highlight>fo<span class=annotation>foo baar foo</span></span> but not centered.</p>
<p>long <span class=highlight>fooooooooooo<span class=annotation>foo baar foo</span></span> and centered.</p>
```

To make the annotation enlarge the annotated text, you can set `.highlight` to be an inline flexbox column (reversed), and align the items to the center:

```css
p {
  font-size: 1.5em
}

.highlight {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  color: red;
}

.highlight .annotation {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>short <span class=highlight>fo<span class=annotation>foo baar foo</span></span> but not centered.</p>
<p>long <span class=highlight>fooooooooooo<span class=annotation>foo baar foo</span></span> and centered.</p>
```

Comment: Shoot. 20s seconds faster!  I recommend adding `-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);` as well, for better support!

Comment: Transform is supported by browsers since IE10, so I most of the time you don't need to bother with prefixes.

Comment: @OriDrori I was wondering, is there a way to let the annotation move the surrounding text in the case that the annotation is longer than the below text? For example to obtain this https://i.imgur.com/WQud82s.png

Comment: @OriDrori I guess we have to put a padding/margin on left and right of `.highlight `, but how to set it automatically?

Comment: That's actually very easy with an inline flexbox. See added answer.

Comment: @OriDrori Wow thank you very much you are very kind! Is it also possible to control the distance between annotation and highlight similarly to the previous method? I'm trying with `height` and `line-height` but they also increase the distance between the lines.

Comment: You can add margin bottom to the `.annotation`.

Comment: @OriDrori Thanks I'm trying it, but it influences the distance between lines too. I'm playing a bit and to obtain the same (almost) spaces as in the other method I added `margin-top:1em` to `.highlight `, and then I had to add `line-height:0.7` and `margin-top:-0.7em` to `.annotation`. It seems a bit tricky, isn't it? :D